# Laravel не видит сервис-провайдер

Tags: php, laravel

Создаю пакет для Laravel. Есть сервис-провайдер `CartServiceProvider`, который лежит в пространстве имен `Alexxosipov\Cart`. Скрин об этом ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также, добавил в config/app.php мой провайдер, также добавил в composer.json пространство имен и сделал `composer dumpautoload`

После этого, приложение перестало работать, выдает следующее:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Alexxosipov\Cart\CartServiceProvider' not found
```

Почему laravel не видит мой класс, хотя phpstorm показывает, что данный провайдер лежит в нужном пространстве имен?

Autoload (корневой composer.json):

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Alexxosipov\\Сart\\": "packages/alexxosipov/cart/src/"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Есть какое-то решение? У меня такая же проблема!

Answer (score 0):

Видимо `composer` не в курсе о существовании этого пространства имён, нужно в файл `composer.json` главный который добавить неймспейс:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        ...
        "Alexxosipov\\Cart\\": "packages/alexxosipov/cart/src"
    }
},
```

Потом уже `composer dump-autoload` и тогда должно всё заработать.

Comment: самое интересное, что уже сделал это. Это и странно.

Comment: @Alexxosipov думаю нужно всё равно этот файл смотреть

Comment: добавил в вопрос